# Run script during HTTP request

Tags: apache, http, cgi, cdn

I'm trying to make my own custom CDN to make my website and my clients websites load more quickly.

I thought of doing something like this:

1. The user uploads the files they want on the CDN to a /cdn folder in their hosting account.
2. The files aren't uploaded to the CDN straight away
3. The files are only uploaded when the file is requested using the CDN

So my question is, how can I cause a script to run during the HTTP request to allow the CDN to go and grab the file?

Can I do something like this using Apache? I'm using Apache web servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are trying to do is essentially have servers load files from one primary server. I would recommend not running a script but using the CDN servers as proxies which cache the responses.

You would have to setup something like this in your apache (virtual)host directive.

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://backend.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend.example.com/

CacheRoot   /var/cache/apache/
CacheEnable disk /
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1
```

See these entries:

- [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html)
- [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- [htcacheclean](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htcacheclean.html)

Hope that helps!